# Using several DispatcherFrames to show Modal windows not working properly, issue can be duplicated with WPF MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem showing modal windows in my application. My application functions like a web browser in that it can host multiple windows (i.e. the same application runs in two or more windows). Due to this, I want Modal windows to only be modal to the window that called it (so if I have two windows open, each window can have its own modal window). This means I can't use ShowDialog() as it blocks the entire application.

I implemented the solution proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964229/4453305) stackoverflow answer by using DispatcherFrames and Dispatcher.PushFrame(). This seemed to work, but after some testing I've found the following:
I start the application, open up a new window, open up a Modal window in the first window and then a Modal window in the second. Then I close the first Modal window, set the DispatcherFrame.Continue to false, but the PushFrame() does not return control to the code that called the method to show the modal window until the Modal window belonging to the second window has also been closed. I suspect this happens because when the first Modal window closes, it returns control to the second DispatcherFrame belonging to the other Modal window instead of the Application DispatcherFrame. However, if I close the second Modal window first, it works the way it should and returns control.

As an additional test, I tested the same situation in a fresh application with WPF MessageBoxes, and it turns out the same problem exists here as well. 
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMessageBoxDispatcherFrame.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="OpenMessageBoxClick" Content="Open message box" />
            <Button Click="OpenNewWindowClick" Content="Open new window" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenMessageBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine("MessageBox closed");
    }

    private void OpenNewWindowClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new MainWindow { ShowInTaskbar = true };
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

If I open up a second window, and open up a message box in each of these two windows, MessageBox.Show() will only return once the second opened MessageBox has been closed (so the first one blocks until the second one has been closed).

Is this a known issue? Working as intended? Are there any workarounds?
I have been able to create something close to what I want by using async/await, but this requires all methods that wants to call a MessageBox/Modal window to be async. What is the best way to show Modal windows the way I want?

Comment: I know, that this is a different way, but instead of tricks with dispatcher, I'd recommend you to look at this: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Home . In fact, this is an overlay-based approach, which behaves *like* modal window without a real window. If you can't use 3rd party packages, you can easily implement this approach yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dennis. It's not a good solution for me as I need the call to be blocked until the Modal window and MessageBox returns (no callbacks), as the decision in the MessageBox decides further program flow.

Comment: It Sound somehow you would like to use multibe Applications. The ShowDialog is ( like you experienced ) bound to the Calling Application Dispatcher. Both ( +n ) windows will be run in the same dispatcher and use it for there work. You cannot stop the dispatcher for only one Window, this will always effect all other windows because there are using it too. The most simple solution would be to Spawn a Messagebox or your own window and set the Enabled property of the calling window to false. By using your own window you could also take advantage of the TopMost property.

Comment: This still leaves me with the problem of getting the return-value from f.ex a MessageBox. Typically you'd do "var result = MessageBox.Show()" and use that result in further execution. This is what I want to achieve. It is possible to use a callback method when the MessageBox/Modal window closes, but that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't get your point. You want to spawn multibe MessageBoxes and collect the result while waiting inside your window? By setting Enabled to false you prevent to get input from the User on the window and by calling Show() you get the info. That is the known usage of the MessageBox. If you would like to do it otherwise you could simple wrap up the MessageBox into a Task and then await the completing of that task. Is it that you would like to achieve? if so i will add an Answer with example code

Comment: I can't use MessageBox.Show() because it can lead to issues of the first MessageBox not returning until the second MessageBox in a different window has closed (see code-snippet above). I need a solution that will support multiple, separate MessageBoxes that are not dependant on one another. I can't use .Show() on MessageBox or .ShowDialog() on Window. I've done something with Tasks and await which works OK, but was hoping there was another solution. Some third party libraries that I use don't support await on some operations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am afraid there is no .net Build in solution for your case. The only way to accomplish that would be to create AppDomains for each window to host each window in a Separate Application. But this would be the Nuke Solution. My Advice, use the Task approach or build your own MessageBox. But without multibe domains you will not get rid of a Task.