# Access to styles from several UI Threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading

Our team developing rich WPF application.

Recently we added logic to show some view as independent non-modal window. User have ability to open as many such windows as he wants. It works good, but if any window will show modal confirmation - then all windows will be blocked.

We found solution - open non-modal windows in separate thread. And now we have issue with shared resources - "InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

It's related with reference to Style in xaml during creation of view in separate thread.

Styles exists in separate project.

What solution could be here?

Code, which shows window in separate thread:

```
    Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            new Window().Show(); // simplified, here are creation of 
            // window, setting datacontext, rest of properties

            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        });

newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
newWindowThread.Start();
```

How to make resources available for all UI threads (under UI thread I mean each separate thread, which creates and shows non modal Window)?

Maybe there are exist another more high level solution?

Comment: We only use a single UI thread to handle the GUI. As a rule of thumb, for the operations in UI thread, we should make sure that they completes as soon as possible. Otherwise the GUI freezes. For time consuming tasks we should use background threads. Actually why do you need to have several UI threads?

Comment: Actually I need to show several independent non-modal windows, but if one of them will show own modal window - only one non-modal window should be blocked.

Comment: As a practice keeping the UI thread busy is not a good way of disabling the window. You can create some property like "bool IsReady" and bind that to IsEnabled in all the related controls. Then you can change editable/uneditable states programmatically for different parts seperately. In that way the UI can be in an uneditable state, but not stuck/freeze. Going to do UI tasks using threads other than The Main Thread,is asking for trouble.

Comment: Check this out for more information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model

Comment: Thank you.

Well, I've found solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22964229/1351850.

We do not need several threads at all. =) Already tested it.